# Prevent quotes to be saved in DB as HTML-entities after sanitization

Tags: mysql, escaping, sanitization

This might be a stupid question but after all the research on best practices – including [this great SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3126175/2126442) that explains sanitizing, validation, escaping for storage and escaping for display – I am still confused.

I have built a routine where I sanitize user input – say, a comment post, or "edit my first name" string – with `$value = filter_var($value, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);`. Given a value of `<a href="https://buy.my.stuff/">O'Hara</a>`, that gets rid of `<a></a>` and similar tags nicely. Then this new value gets validated: error if empty value and field is not nullable;  or if too long;  etc. Lastly, I save that value in the DB using a CakePHP query builder – which, of course, supports binding string values.

But when I then save that value in the DB, it is saved as `O&#39;Hara` instead of `O'Hara` – *because* of said sanitization.

- Am I supposed to decode it back / to yet another format? If so with which method?
- Or, am I to use the sanitized version for validation but then the original value for DB stora-- that can't be it.
- Or is `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING` a flag I need to tweak? The tutorials I've seen [[1]](https://www.codefixup.com/php-filters-to-sanitize-and-validate/) [[2]](https://johnmorrisonline.com/validate-sanitize-user-input-php-using-filter_input-filter_var/) suggest that the flag is enough.

I feel so dumb because that great post mentioned earlier seems to *still* not be enough for me. All I can find are [posts from ~2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6604824/storing-values-with-apostrophes-in-the-database) that say you should bind.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `filter_var` is doing that.

Comment: Use `strip_tags()` if you just want to remove tags.